# How do I set the Chrome AutoSelectCertificateForUrls option in protractor

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am automating some tests with Protractor but cannot figure out how to auto select a certificate for the website under test.
It seems that the **AutoSelectCertificateForUrls** option of Google Chrome should do the trick, but it does not seem to work, or I am not setting it correctly.
This is what I have in my conf file:

    `...
    chromeOptions: {
          prefs: {
            AutoSelectCertificateForUrls: [
              '{"pattern":"[*.]my.website.here","filter":{"ISSUER":{"CN":"My Issuer Here"}}}'
            ]
          }
    ...`

(obviously the website url pattern and cert issuer are anonymised)